# Can't write; duplicate key in table

Tags: magento2, database, sql, quote

> **SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1022 Can't write; duplicate key in table 'quote_address', query was: CREATE TABLE
>   `quote_address`**

**can any body explain this error?**

Comment: which time this error generate ?

Comment: i upgrade my magento 2.28 to 2.3.3 i was getting error quote_address table already exsist then i remove quote address table from my database after that i run command setup:upgrade then following error start to come